# Add a custom command in Visual Studio Code Command Palette

Tags: visual-studio-code, external-tools

Is it possible out of the box or using extensions to add a custom command in the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) in **Visual Studio Code** like "**External Tools**" as in the IDE from [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) or in [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools)?

I would like to be able to run custom **bash**/**cmd** command directly from the **Command Palette**.

Answer (score 18):

You can either use VS Code built-in functionality using shortcuts. Just add to keybindings.json:

```js
{
  "key": "cmd+shift+R",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "clear; rails server\u000D"
  }
},
```

Or you can take a look at this extension: [Command Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edonet.vscode-command-runner)

Comment: how does the argument need to be specified if I want to wrap a selected text in the VS Code document with a prefix and suffix? e.g. turning `text` to `\command{text}`?

Comment: @Marie.P. The feature supports [variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

Answer (score 5):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands

This extension can run it from custom Quick Pick (like command palette, but shows only your items). Command id is `commands.openAsQuickPick`

---

There's no api to seamlessly add commands to Command Palette [#1422](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1422), but it's possible to modify `package.json` what that extension does when this setting is enabled:

```js
"commands.populateCommandPalette": true,
```

With this setting it will not update Command Palette until the editor is reloaded. It might be an ok experience if you don't do that very often.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [multiCommand Extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to build your custom commands, which you can access through the Command Palette. `Ctrl+Shift+P` > `Multi command` > `custom command`.

I know it's not ideal, but I guess you can open multi command with a key binding and then it's almost what you want. Plus the feature that you can execute multiple commands with this extension.

Answer (score -2):

This guy wrote something where you can customize the toolbar. https://github.com/AdamAnandUS/AdamsTool

Maybe add to it with a new StatusBarItem that registers a command you want to run.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#commands.registerCommand

There are also many VS Code Extensions that might do what you want already. https://stackify.com/top-visual-studio-code-extensions/

Comment: unfortunately none of the above is suitable

Answer (score -6):

Go to tools, External tools in visual Studio. Click Add, name the new command then you can point to a batch file command using the browse ellipses. When you save it, you will then see the new menu item under tools.

Comment: i need this for **Visual Studio Code**